# Yocto Recipe - Override python module version

Tags: python, yocto, layer, recipe, yocto-recipe

I've created a layer to install some python modules, but some of them are already included in a third party layer I need (meta-openembedded). The version of python modules installed by the other layer is lower than that I need.
I changed my layer priority, and I set it higher than that of the other layer.
I tried to do the build, but the installed python modules version is still that of *meta-openembedded* layer.

If I execute `bitbake-layers show-layers` my custom layer has a higher priority.

Is there something else I need to do?

Here my layer structure:

```
meta-chiarini
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf <---- (BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-one = "10")
├── recipes-python
│   └── paho-mqtt
│       └── python3-paho-mqtt_1.6.1.bb
```

Here my `layer.conf`:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-chiarini"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-chiarini = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-chiarini = "10"

LAYERDEPENDS_meta-chiarini = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-chiarini = "dunfell"
```

Here `python3-paho-mqtt_1.6.1.bb`:

```
SUMMARY = "MQTT version 5.0/3.1.1 client class"
HOMEPAGE = "http://eclipse.org/paho"
AUTHOR = "Roger Light <roger@atchoo.org>"
LICENSE = "Eclipse Public License v2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=8e5f264c6988aec56808a3a11e77b913"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/dd/4b75dcba025f8647bc9862ac17299e0d7d12d3beadbf026d8c8d74215c12/paho-mqtt-1.6.1.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "bdb20f88db291fdb4a0fe804c0f29316"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "2a8291c81623aec00372b5a85558a372c747cbca8e9934dfe218638b8eefc26f"

S = "${WORKDIR}/paho-mqtt-1.6.1"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

inherit setuptools3
```

Comment: Can you provide the python recipe so I can enhance my answer for your example ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I've added more details

Answer (score 3):

Generally when working with multiple versions of one recipe, here is the idea:

- If the two layers have the same priority, bitbake chooses the highest version in the two layers
- If one of the layers is higher, bitbake chooses the highest version in the highest priority layer

If you want to force a particular version:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_<recipe> = "<version>"
```

**NOTE**: Make sure that the recipes have the same name in `<name>_<version>.bb`

Here is an example:

```
meta-one
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf <---- (BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-one = "7")
├── recipes-one
│   └── one
│       └── one_1.0.bb
├── recipes-one-one
│   └── one
│       └── one_2.0.bb
```

```
meta-two
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf <---- (BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-two = "8")
├── recipes-one
│   └── one
│       └── one_3.0.bb
```

`meta-two` has the highest priority, so when I run:

```
bitbake -s | grep ^one
```

output is:

```
one                 :3.0-r0
```

- Changing them to the same priority gives the same output.
- Changing `meta-one` to be higher (9) gives the highest version in `meta-one`:

```
one                 :2.0-r0
```

Even if it selects automatically the highest version, you can still select a minor version manually:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_one = "1.0"
```

again, `bitbake -s | grep one` gives:

```
one                 :2.0-r0                  :1.0-r0
                       ^                        ^
                       |                        |
(you have 2.0 as       |                        |
 highest version) ------                        |
                                                |
(but you selected 1.0) --------------------------
```

Now, changing the two layers to the same priority with the selection of `1.0` should shows that you have `3.0` as highest version but you selected `1.0`:

```
one                 :3.0-r0                  :1.0-r0
```

**NOTE**:

- The placement of the recipe in each layer is not important to be the same path as:

  - meta-one/recipes-one/one
  - meta-two/recipes-one/one

it is just recommended for readability and organization.

The most important thing is the recipe name matching:

- Main recipe: one_1.0.bb
- one_2.0.bb (OK)
- onee_2.0.bb (NOK, Other entire recipe)

Answer (score 0):

Using command `bitbake -s | grep paho-mqtt` I got a log with the issue.
The License value added in `python3-paho-mqtt_1.6.1.bb` wasn't using the right format.

So I've changed:

```
LICENSE = "Eclipse Public License v2.0"
```

to:

```
LICENSE = "EPL-2.0 | EDL-1.0"
```

I used `pipoe` to generate `.bb` files, and it did't found the right license format, so I've added it manually, but without using the short format.